# Why does the author proposed the HBase Tall-Thin schema over Short-Wide described inside?

Tags: java, hbase, bigdata

I'm reading about ***Tall-Thin vs Short-Wide HBase schema designs*** and the author proposes the following which's reasoning I don't understanding:

> It's best to consider the Tall-Thin design as we know it will help in
>   faster data retrieval by enabling us to read the single column family
>   for user blog entries at once instead of traversing through many rows.
>   Also, since HBase splits take place on rows, data related to a
>   specific user can be found at one region server.

Their proposed ***Short-Wide design*** of a blog site schema is below (where there's a row per writer and each new blog entry is a new column):

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
|                    |     BECF (Blog entry Column family)
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| RowKey (UserID)    | BECF:BT | BECF:BT | BECF:BT | BECF:BT | 
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| WriterA            | Entry1  | Entry2  | Entry3 
| WriterB            | EntryA  | EntryB  | ...
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Their proposed ***Tall-Thin design*** is below (where each new blog entry is a new row):

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
|                            |   BECF (Blog entry Column family)
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| RowKey (UserID+TimeStamp)  |   BlogEntriesCF:Entries
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| WriterATimeStamp1          | Entry1 
| WriterATimeStamp2          | Entry2
| WriterATimeStamp3          | Entry3
| WriterBTimeStamp1          | EntryA
| WriterBTimeStamp2          | EntryB
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

- Why does the author think the tall-thin design is better because "enabling read the single column family for user blog entries at once instead of traversing through many rows"?
- Wouldn't the Short-Wide design allow reading only a single row to fetch for all the entries? Therefore, a better design?

Answer (score 5):

Well, first thing you bypass is row locking.

Say you have a wide row and you need to update it.
This means this row has to be locked. No other writer can update it at that moment because it's locked. They have to wait until the lock is released.

With tall and thin, the data is contained in one field in a short row, which updating it, doesn't cause problems for other writers who want to update their thing, which is in a seperate row.

The tall and thin also lends itself for making dynamic relationships, expanding the userbase, faster indexes, better response times.

Humanly readable it's not really, but for machines it easier to cope with, join, modify, alter structures.

If you have a Object Relational Mapping interface(like Java Hibernate, php Eloquent, etc...) it becomes absurdly easy to make it into oneToMany or ManyToMany relationships and update, modify, poll the objects as a whole.

Tall and Thin Also allows for the same data objects to be easely implemented somewhere else, without the need for views to sanitise / remove the junk data.

For example:

I have a database of prices for product A, product B, product C
The prices have dates they are active corresponding with seasons(christmas etc..). All products in my example are governed by same seasons

wide:

```
  date_from | date_to    | ProductA_price | ProductB_price | ProductC_price
  22-10-2000| 22-11-2000 | 100            | 110            | 90
  23-11-2000| 26-12-2000 | 200            | 210            | 190
  27-12-2000| 22-01-2001 | 100            | 110            | 90
```

Now if you wish to add an extra product you have to do the following:

- Modify table. This can be very expensive on a large table to do, causing outage
- update prices causing a lot of row locks
- Modify queries. Queries are used ALL OVER THE PLACE. They all have to account the extra column, especially if `select *` is used.
- Modify implementing code. There's an extra column, sloppy loops might break. Arrays iterators need to be modified to account for extra product.
- Stuff will break for a long time after the change if the software base is a bit aged.
- update hardcoded references to table names

Tall:

```
table: Products
id | product_name
1  | ProductA
2  | ProductB
3  | ProductC

table: Periods
id| name    | date_from | date_to
1 | autumn  | 22-10-2000| 22-11-2000
2 | xmas    | 23-11-2000| 26-12-2000
3 | newyear | 27-12-2000| 22-01-2001

table: Prices
product_id | period_id | price
1          | 1         | 100
2          | 1         | 110
3          | 1         | 90
1          | 2         | 200
2          | 2         | 210
3          | 2         | 190
1          | 1         | 100
2          | 1         | 110
3          | 1         | 90
```

Now if you wish to add an extra product you have to do the following:

- Add product to table products
- Add entries in table prices for perioddate > now()

Since it's all relational, the code already treats it relational and will read it as such, and just add it it existing code flow.

Answer (score 1):

Your quote is from the book ["learning hbase"](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-hbase/9781783985944). Quote is inaccurate, but it is the good news :)

See how author really describes **Tall-Thin**

> In a **Tall-Thin** table design, the table grows downwards more quickly than towards the right-hand side. [...]
>
> RowKey(UserID+TimeStamp) |  BlogEntriesCF:Entries ----------------------------------------+-------------------------------
>    Writer**A**TimeStamp1     | HBaseEntry
>    Writer**B**TimeStamp2     | HadoopEntry
>    Writer**A**TimeStamp3     | HadoopEntry
>     ...            |  ...

Note that row-keys are **out of order** which is different from your example which explains the confusion. This example explains the need for example for WritterA to

> traverse many rows.

However hbase doesn't work like that, it actually sorts the keys before writing them (technically mutations go unsorted into WAL but if everything is alright, WAL is not used, and if it is used, mutations are replayed onto MemStore which holds the region data).

> Since HBase splits take place on rows, data related to a specific user can be found at one region server.

That part seem to logically relate to **Short-Wide**...

So to sum up, i think this part of the book might need a review.
See this excellent [blog post](https://www.mapr.com/blog/in-depth-look-hbase-architecture) from MapR, for quick overview of Hbase under the hood.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly. The author's quote I provided ***accurately*** is actually ***incorrect***? Also, since **Tall-Thin** requires traversing many rows, would that make data retrieval slower? In other words, for retrieval, **Short-Wide** is better? For write heavy, **Tall-Thin** is better since it doesn't require locking? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, first, you didn't provide accurate quote.I am looking at safari version of it. What you wrote is correct but it is not how the author understands it. Regarding Schema vs Load, it is more complex question because scan can be quite fast. Sometimes it is better to fetch a few rows from many machines then fetching one very wide 600MB row from one machine. Best thing to do is try with data you have, or generate something that would simulate that, hope this helps..

Comment: There is a row width depending on your cluster setup and average column size in bytes, where Short-Wide becomes less effective for reads then Tall-Wide, makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

"Narrow, or stacked data is presented with one column containing all the values and another column listing the context of the value. This is often easier to implement, addition of a new field does not require any changes to the structure of the table, however it can be harder for people to understand."

From "Wide and Narrow data", Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_and_narrow_data [accessed 29.12.16]

I assume that it means that if you want to get the pure list of values without caring about their context, you just read off a column. If you wanted to do that in short-wide data structures, you'd have to find the row and reach the desired column, and that for every row instead of in a single read.

Regards,